# Superposition Principle problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got stuck in this problem.

[image: Problem]

after getting $ y = y(x) = c_1e^{x} + c_2e^{-x}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x\sinh(x)$

I'm not sure what's next.

Comment: What I was thinking is that I should get the general form of cosh(x) = y, then get y' and y'' so I can replace it. After that I got stuck because I got A-A=0.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution, which is correct, is a function of $x$, i.e.,

$ y = y(x) = c_1e^{x} + c_2e^{-x}+\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sinh(x)$. So the initial condition $y(0)=2$ tells you that when $x=0,$ $y = 2$, i.e.,

$y(0) = c_1e^{0} + c_2e^{-0}+\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)\sinh(0) = c_1 + c_2 = 2.$

Comment: Isn't that obvious...

Comment: If it is, then I'm unsure what your question is.

Comment: I made an extra comment.

Comment: All you have to do now is solve for $c_1$ & $c_2$. From $y(0)=2$ you get the equation $c_1 + c_2 =2$ (above). Use $y'(0) =12$ to get one more algebraic equation for $c_1$ & $c_2.$ Then solve for the coefficients and you're done.

Comment: I got everything, but got stuck with the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

$$y(x) = c_1e^{x} + c_2e^{-x}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x\sinh(x)$$
$$y'(x) = c_1e^{x} - c_2e^{-x}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sinh(x)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)x\cosh(x)$$

$y(0) = c_1e^{0} + c_2e^{-0}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)0\sinh(0)=2$

$y'(0) = c_1e^{0} - c_2e^{-0}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sinh(0)+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)0\cosh(0)=12$

$$\text{Solve}\quad\begin{cases}
c_1 + c_2=2\\
c_1 - c_2=12
\end{cases}\quad\text{for }c_1\text{ and }c_2$$